# Too fast response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, transactions

I have an ASP.NET-MVC application that:

- opens a db transaction
- updates a cart status and other things
- submits this cart to another web server via an HttpRequest
- register in database the transmission with its code status
- send a confirmation mail, that the command has been sent
- then if no error has occurs commit the transaction else rollback it.

Normally, after that the distant server sends another web request to my application to a controller action that will update the previous transmission and set an aknowledge field.

My problem is that the distant web server sometimes is very fast and sends the aknowledge status **before** the transmission insertion in the database is committed, so the update fails. How could I prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an AWESOME problem to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make your commit operation in two stages. First is too create record. Then do processing like create mail and so on. And second to make real(logical) commit.

```
using(var db = new Db(){
  db.Insert(
} // This will commit first stage

// Send email do other stuff

using(var db = new Db(){
  var t = db.getTransmission()
   r.Commited = true;
   db.Save();
} // This will logically commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the database, commit and mark as inactive or invalid, then take away this mark once you get our acknowledgement status?

I may be misunderstanding what exacty it is you're doing.